# Expressing the Uncountable Hat Paradox mathematically

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle, equivalence-relations, axiom-of-choice

I came across this article https://jaydaigle.net/blog/what-is-the-axiom-of-choice/#fnref:7 and was wondering how would one mathematically express and explain the Uncountable Hat Puzzle (under the same heading on the page) since there are no definite ordered "steps", just a couple of assumptions? I have only started studying about equivalence relations and real coordinate spaces so i am not very sure how to go about this.

I would appreciate any and all help on this >:)

Comment: Hardin and Taylor have several papers about these sort of things. I think the case with $\Bbb R$ is something with a predictor (I think that was the name?), namely, a function $F$ such that given $g=f\restriction(-\infty,t))$, $F(g)=f(t)$. So what you want is to have a predictor for a certain collection of functions, with maybe a small set for mistakes (where small can be null, meager, etc.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila can you help me with the paper on this topic? i found several about infinite colors but they're quite different from this one.

Comment: I think https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2008.11920502 is the relevant paper here.

Comment: Thank you @AsafKaragila!! I'll go through it :)